# TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable when I generate LazyDatetime

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, datetime, django-models

[Link to source code of `lazy` function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/functional.py#L72)

I have a field in database:

```
paid_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

I try to generate `lazy datetime` for this field

```
paid_at = lazy(datetime.date.today, datetime.date)
```

I generate date (30.01.2020).

But I get error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`.

1. How can I generate date**time**?
2. How can I fix error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`?
3. How can I get yestarday datetime?

If I write 
`str(lazy(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=4), datetime.date)())`
I get error `TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable`

Comment: you can try .strftime()

Answer (score 0):

```
(lazy(datetime.datetime.today, 
    datetime.date)() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```